# Mapbox GL - transition animations for unclustering and for active feature

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In Mapbox GL JS, I'm looking to use clustering + use a different icon for one feature which is currently defined as "active". I want the necessary transitions (unclustering + change of the active feature) to be animated, but can't find a way of making this all happen.

Mapbox provides an [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) showing how to implement clusters, which uses different layers for the clusters and for non-clustered features. This technique can also be used for rendering the "active" feature in its own layer with a different image. When a cluster breaks ("unclusters") into features, it basically gets removed from the clusters layer, and the features get added to the "unclustered" features layer. But this doesn't allow adding a transition animation, since there isn't really a transition here. I would like to show the cluster splitting into features, with each feature moving to its respective location.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Some ideas that don't quite provide a full answer:

1. Use Leaflet with the [markercluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) and its "spider" behavior for clustering. This works and provides a nice "spider" transition animation for unclustering. However there is no "official" binding between leaflet and Mapbox GL, so I'm reluctant to use that (there is just [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) which I would need to modify and it's based on undocumented Mapbox internals). Also I'm now sure whether this is good or bad performance-wise with thousands of features. And I know from experience that adding an animation to modify the shape of Leaflet markers (for active/inactive transitions) doesn't really work.
2. Use markers in Mapbox, instead of layers, but then how to do any sort of clustering?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reasonable way to implement this just using Mapbox GL JS, short of learning WebGL and implementing a custom source.

But I wouldn't write off the Leaflet+Mapbox approach - in my experience, the performance is ok (though I haven't tested with clusters or what you're trying to do).

There is a similar approach with OpenLayers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html I have also used this and it worked fine.

Finally, it seems there are quite a few Leaflet and OpenLayers libraries that specifically solve the animated clustering issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/how-to-create-animated-cluster-markers-in-openlayers-leaflet (And most of these answers are very old, so perhaps there are more libraries now).

Comment: Thanks Steve, will look also at OpenLayers and update here.
Learning WebGL sounds like a good idea but not quite in scope of this project :-)

Comment: Update:

I tried to work using the mapbox-gl-leaflet binding between leaflet and mapbox-gl (which took some work to get going as we're using react-leaflet).

Unfortunately then I ran into a major problem with this binding, related to markers:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet/issues/143

So back to using tiles for now, but will probably opt for either OpenLayers or native Mapbox GL.